# Use Custom Generator @GenericGenerator for multiple entities with Association

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two Java Classes:

The first Class **Class1** Looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "mydb", schema = "dbo", name = "[myTable1]")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "myGen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "myGen",
            strategy = "Y.X.z.generator.MyGen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private String text;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Class2 class2;
```

The second Class **Class2** Looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "mydb", schema = "dbo", name = "[myTable2]")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "myGen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "myGen",
            strategy = "de.svg.releasenotes.generator.MyGen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private String text;
```

As you can see that Class 1 has an association ManyToOne against Class 2.
Class 1 as well as Class 2 use the same GenericGenerator ( Y.X.z.generator.MyGen ).

The Generator looks like this:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MyGen implements IdentifierGenerator {


    @Override
    public Serializable generate(
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj)
            throws HibernateException {

        String query = String.format("select %s from %s",
                session.getEntityPersister(obj.getClass().getName(), obj)
                        .getIdentifierPropertyName(),
                obj.getClass().getSimpleName());

        Stream<Long> ids = session.createQuery(query).stream();

        Long max = ids.max(Long::compare).orElse(0L);

        return max + 1;
    }

}
```

The generator makes retrieves the max ID from the DB.TableX and increments it at 1.

When I call my POST endpoint I get the following error:

```
2022-11-15 15:27:26.214 ERROR 276510 --- [io-13778-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabledFor(SLF4JLogger.java:213) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabled(SLF4JLogger.java:121) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1513) ~[log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.isEnabled(Log4j2Logger.java:46) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:98) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.isTraceEnabled(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:54) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1372) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at  Y.X.z.generator.MyGen.generate(MyGen.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:801) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1372) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at  Y.X.z.generator.MyGen.generate(MyGen.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:801) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1372) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
```

...

Which shows that MyGen has a StackOverflowError.

Any ideas how I can work around my problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error you have posted isn't corresponding to the code you posted.  There is some kind of infinite recursion happening here and it seems like the culprit (in your code) is here:  `at de.svg.releasenotes.generator.ReleaseNotesAuthorIdGenerator.generate(ReleaseNotesAuthorIdGenerator.java:25) ~[classes/:na]`  when you call the `list` method.  In your sample generator code you aren't calling this method... What does the your actual code look like at this location?

Comment: I have corrected this in Error message. I used the Y.X.z.generator.MyGen to change the package information here in Stackoverflow. 
In principle there is an infinite loop inside the generator. MyGen is my Custom Generetor which is used in Class1 and Class2.  My guess: Since Class1 and Class2 are in @ManyToOne relationship, and the two classes use the same generator, StackOverFlowError occurs. 
One more information and that is when I debug the error the line returns:

`Stream<Long> ids = session.createQuery(query).stream();`

the StackOverFlowError, after the call from MyGen in Class2.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it seems like you may have found a bug in hibernate, but it is hard to tell.

The good news is that, if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you don't need a custom generator, which means you should be able to work around your problem.

You can use the [`SEQUENCE` generation strategy](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#GenerationTypeSEQUENCE) to achieve monotonically increasing ids for your entities:

```
...
public class Class1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "class1_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="class1_generator")
    private Long id;
...
```

```
...
public class Class2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "class2_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="class2_generator")
    private Long id;
...
```